# Detect a "crash" electrically or mechanically

Tags: raspbian-jessie, troubleshooting

Is there a mecahnical or electrical way to find out if a raspberry pi 3b has crashed? measuring voltage at a certain pin or similar?

Comment: you could write a python script that pulsed a pin on and off then you could check to see if it was pulsing with another circuit or something...

Comment: @scitronboy Why not make that an answer?  The Pi does have watchdog support.